# UDEV assign ATTRS{variable} to ENV{variable}

Tags: udev

I am writing my first udev rule. I read many how tos but can't find a way
to assign `ATTRS{variable}` to `ENV{variable}`

in order to have access to that variable from RUN

like `RUN+="/bin/mkdir/%E{variable}"`

because with `RUN+="/bin/mkdir/ATTRS{variable}"` it doesn't work.

I tried to use `$ATTRS{variable}`, `%ATTRS{variable}`, `ATTR{serial}`, `$ATTR{serial}`, `%ATTR{serial}` with no success.

The variable itself exists 100%

thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would delete this question but, probably, this could save one's time

So I used: `ENV{variable}="$attr{variable}"`

Comment: i have rndis device. `udevadm info --query=all --path=/sys/class/net/rndis0 --attribute-walk` shows ATTRS{product}=="ZTE Wireless Ethernet Adapter" in /devices/platform/ehci-platform/usb1/1-1 . how to copy ATTRS{product} to attr{product} ?